# React native how to play h264 (elementary) stream

Tags: javascript, react-native, h.264

I need to play the h264 streams received from the camera in react-native app. Is it possible to play raw h264 data without converting to other codec?

Comment: Check this link https://hackernoon.com/video-streaming-in-your-react-native-app-feae1c6ae4e2

Comment: any luck with this

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers are fine with the h264 codec, but they will not play the raw bitstream. The stream must be wrapped into an mp4 container before the browser will load it.